# Unable to install apps on iPhone, either free or paid

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, password

I had an Apple ID in one country and was unable to update the debit card, which had the same currency and a different country address.

Now I cannot install free or paid apps. I tap `Get` and am prompted for a password. If I put the wrong one, I see:

```
Verification failed
Your Apple ID or password is incorrect
Cancel Try Again
```

When the password is right, I see a spinning circle and then I see `Get` again, just as before.

I tried [this thread](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389) to sign in from my name in the Settings app. I get prompted for a different email address, to which I say no put my email and password, and nothing happens either. I changed the sign-in away from the other email, which was still connected to the Game Center (from Settings > Game Center), and tried signing in again with the same result.

Everything seems to be in order with my Apple ID, which I can see on a desktop browser with my current country.

How can I install free or paid apps?

I am using an iPod Touch with iOS 12.4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple for support and they were unable to explain why this happened. They suggested three things:

- reset network settings, then enter wi-fi settings again: this failed,
- install the latest software version (12.4.8): this worked,
- restore the iPod to factory settings: I did not try this.

To see if it works, I could either have signed in from the Settings app, which requests the password for my Mac computer, or to sign in from the App Store app.